# Detect Fast User Switch Linux

Tags: linux, performance, x11

I'm currently attempting to detect when a user has fast-user-switched to another user on the Linux platform (specifically, Fedora 14-16, RedHat 4.7-6.x, CentOS 4-6, OpenSuse 10-11).  I've been looking for something similar to the WTSRegisterSessionNotification() function that is available on Windows, but all I've come across is a bunch of references to bugs in the Wine software.

Has anyone else run across this snag?  There seems to be a ton of resources on how to do this on Windows and Mac OS X (which is fine), but on Linux there seems to be nothing...

EDIT:
Apparently, on newer systems (at least Fedora 16) [this](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd-loginctl.html) may appear to be a viable option.  I wonder if it has a DBus interface...More to come soon!

Comment: Perhaps look for an appropriate dbus signal from the display manager?

Comment: But why would you even want to know that? It sounds like a design error to me, save perhaps for a few special cases such as xlock.

Comment: @jørgensen There are perfectly good reasons to do this, eg spawn a VNC server to remote the active X server, and respawn it whenever a FUS happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that the most useful way of getting at this information is to use the [ConsoleKit DBus interface](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#id310672).

The following procedure outlines how to enumerate the sessions and determine if they are active or not:

1.) Enumerate the sessions using the following:

```
    Bus:    org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit
    Path:   /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager
    Method: org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessions
```

What is returned is an array of object paths that export the Session interface.  These, in turn, can be queried using DBus to get their appropriate properties.  For example, I used dbus-send to communicate with ConsoleKit to enumerate the sessions in my system:

`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessions`

And what I received in return was the following:
`method return sender=:1.15 -> dest=:1.205 reply_serial=2
   array [
      object path "/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2"
   ]`

2.) Using the returned object path(s), I can query them for their attributes, such as if they are active or not using the following:

```
    Bus:    org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit
    Path:   /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2
    Method: org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session.IsActive
```

Depending on the method, I can query what I need from the session(s)!  Using the ConsoleKit interface I can also retrieve the identifier for the current session, so I can always query it to see if it's active when I need to.  Just for fun, here's the output of the following command:

`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Session.IsActive`

> > method return sender=:1.15 -> dest=:1.206 reply_serial=2
> >        boolean true

Neat.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I need to tell you I'm not an expert in this area, but I have enough knowledge to give you pointers to places where you may go and learn more. So I may be wrong in some ways.

My guess is:

- this is not easy
- for most methods you may implement there are probably many ways to trick them into believing something that's not true, which may lead to security problems
- your method may depend on the:

  - chosen Linux Distribution
  - version of the Distribution
  - Desktop Environment
  - Display Manager

As far as I know (and I may be wrong if something changed during the last years), fast user switching is implemented by launching another X server on another VT. So one way *would* be to detect if there are multiple X servers running.

But there are many cases where there multiple X servers running and it's not because of fast user switching. Examples: Multiseat or even simple Xephyr logins.  With Xephyr and XDMCP, you may even have the same user logged in twice in a non-fast-user-switching case.

I started googling about this and found this old web page:

- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Desktop/FastUserSwitching

If things haven't changed since then, you should study ConsoleKit and PolicyKit (and also DeviceKit and maybe Systemd today) and their DBus APIs.

There are also the commands `ck-list-sessions` and `ck-launch-session`. But I believe you can fool these commands easily: try to `ck-launch-session xterm` and then `ck-list-session`.

Why exactly are you trying to detect fast user switching? What's your ultimate goal? Maybe you can solve your problem without trying to detect fast user switch...

Comment: And it so came that ConsoleKit is also obsolete by now on certain distributions that moved to systemd-logind.

Comment: Yes, I saw that old web page.  In fact it seemed useful until I noticed the date on it.  The reason why I'm trying to detect fast user switching is because I have a notification applet that runs in the system tray, and I only want it to produce a beep to notify the user if and only if it is running in an active user session (it controls not only the system speaker but a hardware buzzer built into one of our products).  The hardware buzzer is configurable by each user in that every user has the option to enable/disable it for their session via the applet.  So, detecting FUS is necessary.

Comment: You really should consider that, in some machines, there are 2 users logged in and actively using the computer. Don't assume there's just one X server and/or there's just one user logged in.

Comment: I am definitely considering that option, and my applet is capable of handling the case where there are multiple users logged in and using the computer.  This only poses an issue if one has disabled the hardware buzzer and the other hasn't, but there isn't much I can do in that case.  Still, I would like to be as smart as I can about detecting if it's running in an active user session, because from my user feedback it's more likely that a FUS has happened or a user has logged in via a VNC client or something of the sort.

Comment: See my answer for a secure, foolproof, cross-distro way of detecting FUS. By watching the virtual terminal with an ioctl, you can be absolutely sure what's on the console session and when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by polling to be sure of working on all machines (you obviously don't have to have DBus running to do user switching!).

Solaris, HP-UX, and others, do not do user switching on the console.

Platforms to support: linux, FreeBSD, AIX. Linux/BSD use virtual terminals; AIX uses `/dev/lft0` if you're interested.

Suppose you want to reliably and securely run a application on the console, and restart it on the new active X server when the console switches to another VT. The problems are that you may or may not have a desktop environment running (some of us use twm!). The session may not have been started via a login manager (you could do Ctrl-Alt-F2 on linux, login, and run `startx` quite happily). The system might not even have xdm/gdm/similar installed.

The dumb solution is the only reliable one: every few seconds, query what the active virtual terminal is (`VT_GETSTATE` on linux, `VT_GETACTIVE` on BSD). If it's changed, you know a switch has happened. If you switched to a non-graphical session (eg with Ctrl-Alt-F1) there won't be an X server active.

Otherwise, you have to hunt hard to find which display number is active. For example, you might see two X servers in `ps`, with display numbers :1 and :2. Which of those is on VT7 though? The final piece of the puzzle, mapping VT numbers to display numbers, is the hardest. This question is answered in [this duplicate question, "Which virtual terminal is a given X process running on?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/which-virtual-terminal-is-a-given-x-process-running-on).